# Adding to Pipeline: Modifier of Prediction of Multi-Label Classifier

Tags: scikit-learn

I've created a pipeline that uses the Random Forest classifier at the end for a multi-label prediction.

Now sometimes the predictions are all 0 for all the classes. In that case I'd want to modify the prediction such that the first label defaults to 1.

E.g.,

- The prediction (0,1,0,0,1,0) stays (0,1,0,0,1,0)
- The prediction (0,0,0,0,0,0) becomes (1,0,0,0,0,0)

What's a way to achieve this within the sklearn Pipeline. Is there somekind of Prediction-Modifier class that I could extend and implement and then add to the pipeline?

So all I'd like to do is to modify the predictions from the Random Forest classifier once they are done. I can do this easily in code, but I don't know how to do this within the pipeline, such that I can do it within grid search for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've resorted to extending the Random Forest Classifier as follows:

```
class ModifiedRandomForestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier):
  def predict(self, X):
    y_pred = super().predict(X)
    # default to first class if multi-label prediction is (0,0,...,0)
    y_pred[y_pred.sum(axis=1) == 0, 0] = 1
    return y_pred
```